# Libreoffice Calc window is minimized when started (ooSetupFactoryWindowAttributes is set to zeros)

Tags: libreoffice

I have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 install and have the following problem.

When opening Libreoffice Calc, the window is very small on the top left and only two x are visible.

The code in `registrymodifications.xcu` is as follows:

```
<item oor:path="/org.openoffice.Setup/Office/Factories/org.openoffice.Setup:Factory['com.sun.star.sheet.SpreadsheetDocument']"><prop oor:name="ooSetupFactoryWindowAttributes" oor:op="fuse"><value>72,64,36,26;1;0,0,0,0;</value></prop></item>
```

The problems seem to be the zeros. When deleting the file or manually changing the numbers, they are resetted as soon as the program is started again. I don't have this problem with Libreoffice Writer.

Comment: Running maximized, so I did not notice, but I confirm. However, once you manage to get the window properly sized (using the mouse), it should remember on the next launch. It does for me.

Comment: This link shows same issue with a solution that worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275213/libreofficecalc-window-is-shrunk-to-a-line-and-is-unclickable

Comment: It's probably due to that bug in LibreOffice: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125543 . From what I see, bug is still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Resize the window: move the mouse cursor over the two x that you mentioned until it changes to a resize cursor, and drag to resize the window to your desired sized. Click maximized.
The new size will be remembered.