# LibreOfficeCalc window is shrunk to a line and is unclickable

Tags: libreoffice

I moved the LibreOfficeCalc window from full width to my other screen and suddenly it became just a line:

[image]

[image]

Now I cant find it on my desktop anymore:

[image]

The problem is, even if I close the LibreOfficeCalc from the navbar and reopen it again, its still not visible. Probably because it saved the "line" width as default. I can't find anything to click and expand on my desktop.

What can I do so I can use it again?

I already tried to remove and reinstall it, but the issue remains. Every file that I open is now a line.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274365/

Comment: It's probably all the time the same known bug #125543 in LibreOffice that they still can't fix: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=125543

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually, one still sees the very small window. However, you apparently don't.

Try switching to the window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, which should display the window menu. You can select "Resize", and then use the arrow keys to resize the window. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when done resizing.

In cases where you still can see the extremely small window, you should be able to locate the mouse pointer on one of the corners in such a way that the cursor changes shape to indicate you can resize: <kbd>⇲</kbd>. Drag, and you see you can stretch the window to a decent size.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Resize didnt exactly work,because window is too small, but I could maximize and thenn make it smaller. Thanks again! I wasn't able to use Calc the whole day.. Thank you!

Comment: Great! I always still see the close button, and I can drag the window with the mouse. I don't know what it is that can trigger this resizing to an extremely small window.

Comment: piling on with the GRATITUDE, @vanadium

Answer (score 4):

Here is

- another solution (which, for me, is more convenient)
- a permanent solution (if the file is always opening that way)

1. the quick solution

- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> then choose the file.
- <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>-></kbd> to resize it to the right half of the monitor

2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (To save not just file entries but how the file is presented as well.)