# LibreOffice Calc not opening on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libreoffice

I have an issue with LibreOffice Calc. When I try to start the application, it doesn't show up.

I do have the icon in my dock indicating that it is running. If I click the icon, nothing happens. Holding the key-comb for tabbing through Windows does show an open window, but it can't be selected. All other LibreOffice applications, e.g. Writer, do work without any issue.

I am on kernel 5.4.0-47-generic with Ubuntu 20.04. I have already tried the following steps:

- `sudo apt purge libreoffice && sudo apt install libreoffice`
- Manually deinstaling and installing through the software center (no snap!)
- Upgrading to openjdk-14-jdk (that was a tip in the LibreOffice forum)
- Starting the application from terminal with `libreoffice --calc`

For sanity, I tried in a VM and it works there without a hassle. I am confused.

Comment: That solved my problem. As this is a duplicate, should I delete it?

Comment: Some users may not realize that calc is too small to be seen, but think it is another kind of issue. Therefore, this question should **not** be deleted so that they can find it. You can upvote the question and answers which you found helpful. 

By the way, which of the two links solved the issue? I will mark your question as a duplicate of that.

Comment: The first link solved my question. I already upvoted the answer given there. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibreOfficeCalc window is shrunk to a line and is unclickable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275213/libreofficecalc-window-is-shrunk-to-a-line-and-is-unclickable)